# Error: "Required 'Alpha Access' permission for 'Compute API'" while trying to add a disk

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I created an SuSE 12 SP4 for SAP instance. Now when I try to attach a disk I am getting the below error:

```
Required 'Alpha Access' permission for 'Compute API'
```

I am own of the project and this is the first time I am getting this error.

Anyone know if there is any ongoing issue on GCP or am I missing something?

Thanks.

[image]

Update: I am able to manually create the disk and then attach to the Instance.

Comment: What is your machine type?

Comment: n2-highmem-4. But I don't think there is any relation between the instance type and my issue.

Comment: I tried the same now and got the same message. Appears to me some bug with Google Compute Engine

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a project for SAP purposes and resources related, you should need to have been granted with access to alpha APIs at project level.

You need to [contact](https://cloud.google.com/contact) Sales to get that access

Comment: I am just creating a VM and later tried to attach disk by editing the VM. This is not the first time I am creating such VM. This always worked for me. This time I have to manually create the disk and then attach the disk to the Instance as "attach existing disk". Just to make it clear that if I create a VM and during creation if I add the disk, it works.

Not sure why I am getting this error.

Comment: ok I see, well if this is something that started to happen a few days ago make sense that this is not usual and not related to the above comment, after read your comment I gave myself the task of reviewing it, unfortunately I don't have any status dashboard link to point you to, but there was a transient issue last days but today looks solved, Could you try again?